# Parse Huge Text String String.split() (Or) Regular Expression (Or) Any other Way?

Tags: java

I'm having a text file which has 3,00,000 lines where the line delimiter is '

example,

```
    UNB+UNOA:1+KRR+KRR+050313:1257+1+++++KRR'
    UNH+1+BAPLIE:D:95B:UN:SMDG20'
    BGM++1+9'
    ......
    ......
    .......
```

I want to read the text line by line.

Huge users import similar kind of files to the system.

What is the best way to read the file line by line by delimeting the text?

Can we parse the whole text via regular expression in java? if yes, how to do it?

String.split() might be slower if we have a powerful regular expression to parse the text.

Please help me with your suggestion to achieve the best performance.

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly `new Scanner(myFile).useDelimiter("'")`?

Comment: You may want to delimit only on `'` not immediately preceded by a question mark if it's an EDI file though.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to read lines from a text file just do this...

```
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("YourPath"));
     String line = br.readLine();
     while (line != null) {
            //Do Something...
         line = br.readLine();
     }
     br.close();
```

for example if your text file is :

I

Am

HAPPY

the output is

I

Am

Happy

the same..

Comment: The line delimiter is `'` which means the file would be `I'Am'HAPPY` which readLine would read as a single line.